# Unity Horizontal layout group wont work on load

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, layout

I am using a horizontal layout group for a panel that can have 1 or more children. The problem is that on load, the children are not aligned properly.

But they do get aligned when I do almost anything. When I change play scene screen size, disable layout and then enable it, change any property of horizontal layout group. And it works fine.

Anybody knows the reason behind this, I have even tried quick fixes(which I hate) but it won't work for some reason.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Can you attach ContentSizeFitter to the HorizontalLayoutGroup and see what happens

Comment: Just tried it.. Its not working, the children just move to another location.. but they are not aligned..Thanks for help though..:)

Comment: Try to call CalculateLayoutInputHorizontal(), CalculateLayoutInputVertical(), SetLayoutHorizontal() and SetLayoutVertical() from script.

Comment: Nothing happened.. Although as a quick fix.. I tried disabling layout in scene, then on load enabled it after 1 second using coroutine. It worked. I dont why and how..

Comment: Again, it looks more like a bug. What's your Unity version?

Comment: I am using 5.5.2

Comment: Upgrade your Unity update. That should fix this issue

Comment: Aah.. I think that is just a maybe and I cant take that risk since I am not allowed to switch to a new version without asking my lead, since it will require a lot of code change and testing effort..

Thank you @Programmer